# find if the password is wrong 7z.exe batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, zip, unzip

**i use 7z.exe for plugins batch file**

```
7z.exe x lolpassword.zip -p%pass%
```

i need to know if %pass% is correct to unzip

i try but it not work

```
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto no
if %errorlevel% == 1 goto yes
```

Comment: What makes you think that there are only two possible error levels? The last time I looked `7z.exe`, had, I think, eleven, _(although some of those weren't yet implemented)_. What happens when you enter the incorrect password? What happens when you enter the correct password? You are supposed to provide us with sufficient information for us to assist you with your problem. I've no intention of downloading/installing a third party utility, creating a password protected archive, and performing these tasks myself, in order to work out what is happening on your PC.

Comment: Immediately after the `7z.exe` command, use `ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%` to see the result. Use 7z.exe with an invalid password and examine the ERRORLEVEL value.